# Creating a hierarchy of Java subclasses

Tags: java, abstract

I'm trying to setup a hierarchy of places in java. A place can be large or small, and larger places include smaller sublocations. So, a World contains Countries, Countries contain Cities, and so on down to Buildings and Rooms.

I have created an abstract class called Place that is the parent to all these types. Every Place contains a graph of sublocations, a parent location, and the ability to get parent's sublocations (aka one's neighbors)

The main problem I'm having is that one's parent's sublocations should be instances of one's class, but there's no way to specify this with java.

I've considered hard-coding all the types, so that City's getParent returns a Country and getSublocations returns a Graph of Building, but that creates some problems with altering the functionality of the classes or adding new classes, and involves a horrifying amount of code copying. Are there any other ways to solve this?

EDIT:

Thanks for all the answers. This is what I have so far. It's not perfect but it's not too bad either. The only code I had to copy was the implementation of getNeighbors(). It used to be implemented directly in the abstract class (this.getParent().getSublocations().getEdges(this) ) but that was only one line of code.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
public abstract class Place {
    //World, Region, City, Building, Room
    public enum Direction {
        East, Northeast, North, Northwest, West, Southwest, South, Southeast, Invalid;
        public static Direction fromInt(int i) {
            switch (i) {
            case 0: return East;
            case 1: return Northeast;
            case 2: return North;
            case 3: return Northwest;
            case 4: return West;
            case 5: return Southwest;
            case 6: return South;
            case 7: return Southeast;
            default: return Invalid;
            }
        }
        public static Direction fromAngle(double angle) {
            return fromInt((int) (angle+22.5)/45);
        }
    }

    protected final int locked = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    protected int x, y; //longitude and latitude
    public abstract String getName();
    public abstract <S extends Place> Graph<S> getSublocations();
    public abstract <T extends Place> T getParent();
    public abstract <U extends Place> HashSet<Passage<U>> getNeighbors();

    public final Direction getDirection(Place otherPlace) {
        if (otherPlace == null) {
            return Direction.Invalid;
        } else if (this.getClass() == otherPlace.getClass()) {
            return Direction.fromAngle(Math.atan2(otherPlace.y-y, otherPlace.x-x));
        } else {
            return Direction.Invalid;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can countries contain non-city places? i.e. are you trying to filter sibling places according to type, or are you trying to limit the possible types at a level as they are being added?

Comment: Can you put some code extract? It may help us to understand what you're looking for

Comment: Note that, in the real world, many of these relationships are not strictly hierarchical. There are cities that aren't technically in any country or span multiple states/countries, just to give one example. For simple tasks obviously a hierarchy may be sufficient, but just fair warning it may come back to bite you :)

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to use inheritance (IS-A) where you should use composition (HAS-A). World HAS Country objects, but a Country IS not a World. Countries have Cities, but a City isn't a Country.

Comment: @azurefrog Each tier of Place can only contain lower tier places. So cities only contain buildings.  The mainly desired functionality is that any place returns a place of a specified type when getParent(), getSublocations(), and getNeighbors() is called.

Comment: @dimo44 As an ardent player of Sid Meier's Civilization, I believe that any city not in a country of its own is a city state. So, cities always exist inside countries.

Comment: @Robert The only IS-A relation ship is that World, Region, City etc are all Places.

Comment: @Al1 I added the code for the abstract class place in my answer. The various extensions of this class currently only contain very basic implementations of the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this problem a few times and when you're messing with something like this, I do not recommend using generics in this case because you already know what each Place is going to be returning. Hopefully this code will help.

```
public interface Place {
    // Place can be an abstract class if you want. 
    // Making it abstract could cause some problems because it might make you use generics
    // I recommend an interface
    List<? extends Place> getSublocations();
    Place getParent();
}
public class World implements Place {

    private List<Country> countries;

    @Override
    public List<Country> getSublocations() {
        return this.countries;
    }

    @Override
    public Place getParent() {
        return null;
    }
}
public class Country implements Place {
    private List<City> cities;
    private World parent;

    @Override
    public List<City> getSublocations() {
        return this.cities;
    }

    @Override
    public World getParent() {
        return this.parent;
    }
}
public class City implements Place {
    private Country parent;

    @Override
    public List<? extends Place> getSublocations() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Country getParent() {
        return this.parent;
    }
}
```

There shouldn't be too much copy and pasting in the code, but I would think this is your best option.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that every type directly extends from `Place` (as opposed to something like `City extends Country`, which would be wrong), you should be able to limit your boilerplate with generics, e.g.:

```
public class Place<P extends Place<?, ?>, C extends Place<?, ?>> {
  // ...
  public final P getParent() { ... }
  public final Set<C> getChildren() { ... }
}

public class City extends Place<Country, Building> { ... )
```

In practice, though, you may find it more flexible to simply return `Place` in both cases, and avoid hard-coding in the type system the relationship between different levels of the hierarchy. Should things ever change (e.g. you introduce a `State` type between `Country` and `City`) you'd have to correct every call site that depends on the prior relationship.

Answer (score -1):

take a look at the composite pattern and maybe use some marker intefaces.